# Why does the sub(...) function completely distort my data frame?

Tags: r, gsub

strangely, I didn't come upon this while browsing online. Basically I am trying to apply the sub(...) function to a simple data frame. Please refer to the following example:

```
x <- data.frame(name=c("Hans", "Dieter", "Peter"), age=c(25,26,27))
data <- data.frame(sub("e", "a", x)) #subbing an e for an a
```

The output changes the data frame completely, the first row now contains:

c("Hans", "Diater", "Peter")

The second:

c(25, 26, 27)

Might anybody be so kind and help me out so that I can understand what is going on? Many thanks!

Comment: May be you meant `x$name <- sub("e", "a", x$name)`. The `sub` was applied on the whole dataframe `x` instead of the column 'name' as `sub` expects its `x` argument as `vector`.  You may check `?sub` for more information

Comment: Thank you very much, now it worked out! So if I not mark the exact column the sub(...) function transforms my data.frame to an vector? Thx again

Comment: A data.frame is a `list` with elements  (`column` - generally a a vector) of equal length.  A `list` is different from a `vector`.  According to `?sub`, it expects a vector as input.  Generally, I would look at the documentation of the function before I apply it to understand what the function expects as input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sub()` function is not designed to act on whole dataframes, just on individual vectors.

This should work:

```r
x <- data.frame(name=c("Hans", "Dieter", "Peter"), age=c(25,26,27))
x
#>     name age
#> 1   Hans  25
#> 2 Dieter  26
#> 3  Peter  27

library(tidyverse)
data <- x %>% mutate(name = str_replace(name, "e", "a")) #subbing an e for an a
data
#>     name age
#> 1   Hans  25
#> 2 Diater  26
#> 3  Pater  27
```

or a little shorter without the pipes

```
data <- mutate(x, name = str_replace(name, "e", "a"))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a base R approach with `lapply` to re-build the dataframe with modified values:

```r
## With regex enabled:
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern='a', replacement='e')
## Without regex, fixed string replacement:
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern='a', replacement='e', fixed=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/C2So6p), output:

```r
    name age
1   Hens  25
2 Dieter  26
3  Peter  27
```

**NOTE**: Since the `age` column type changes to `char` as the result, you should revert the column type back to numeric:

```r
df$age <- as.numeric(df$age)
```

If you only want to perform replacements on all columns of type `char`, use

```r
df <- data.frame(name=c("Hans", "Dieter", "Peter"), age=c(25,26,27), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
chr_idx <- sapply(df, is.character)
df[chr_idx] <- lapply(df[chr_idx], gsub, pattern='a', replacement='e', fixed=TRUE)
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/cYTKCj).

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer. What exactly does the fixed=TRUE indicate? I tried to look it up in the manual but do not really understand it. As far as I can see, the output is the same

Comment: @chrtpmdr The `fixed=TRUE` option disables the regex feature, the pattern argument is searched for as a literal string. This speeds up replacement process a lot.